# Multiple Firefox instances using selenium web driver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to run parallel tests using selenium to check the given url has mobile site or not by opening given url in mobile browser using firefox driver.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities("firefox", "3.6.", Platform.LINUX);
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference('general.useragent.override', USER_AGENT);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new java.net.URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444//wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.get(urlString)
```

it is working fine. but if i run multiple tests simultaneously second test is waiting until the first test closes the firefox but i want to open multiple instances simultaneously. if i run 10 tests simultaneously one test should not wait for another test to finish. can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: we need to see your node configuration.  By default, it should be able to run 5 legacy chrome and firefox instances, and 5 wedriver chrome and firefox instances.  Had you customized this at all?

Comment: I executed following commands in two terminals 1.java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub -port 4444
2.java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=6

Comment: When i access http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console?config=true&configDebug=true in browser i am getting following information "listening on http://192.168.1.79:5555
test session time out after 300 sec.
Supports up to 5 concurrent tests from:firefox icon (5 times) updated with grid1 config :No grid1 file specified. To specify one, use -grid1Yml XXX.yml where XXX.yml is a grid1 config file

updated with grid2 config : No hub config file specified. To specify one, use -hubConfig XXX.json where XXX.json is a hub config file

Comment: @Jagadeesh Your environment looks correct.Are you sure that multiple tests are getting triggered against this hub in parallel?

Comment: @A.J i have web application that runs the selenium test in the backend and i am working in local system. when i run web application in multiple tabs i can see only one firefox instance is opening and closing and remaining tabs are still in loading state until the first tab request is finished.

Comment: Yes,I understand that.Question is - how are you triggering multiple tests simultaneously?Grid would need to get parallel requests at the same time to execute tests in parallel.